# how to stop Ubuntu 14.04 from logging me out

Tags: 14.04

I just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 in both my Laptop and Desktop Windows 7 computers.  Now if I walk away from my work for a few minutes, I'm logged out.  At times the screen begins to fade when I pause to think of a word.  I then have to quickly move the mouse or it will log me out.  How do I fix this problem on both computers?

Answer (score 5):

Does it log out out, or go to a lock screen?

Open the dash and type 'settings', then choose 'Brightness and Lock'.  There you can choose a time for how long it is before the screen goes to black, disable the lock function and unclick the 'require my password when waking from suspend' if desired.